# Django - passing argument to custom .save method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a custom .save method on my model. The model has a `start_date` and a `last_edited` value. If the difference between these values is more than 14 days, it should copy/clone itself on save (instead of saving).

You probably already see the problem: infinite recursion. If the clone saves itself, the values will still differ 14 days and the whole copy process will start anew.

Therefore I want to to pass these copies a `'copy'` argument in their .save parameter, in order to prevent them from triggering the copy process themselves.

To this end I've written the following code:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    #check if a submission is older than the 'create a new one' threshold
    #Create a new one if that is the case

    delta = self.last_edited - self.start_date

    print(args)
    print(kwargs)

    if 'copy' in kwargs or 'copy' not in args:
        print('cloning!')

        if delta.days >= 14:

            clone = self
            clone.pk = None
            clone.save('copy')

    super(AssessmentSubmission, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, for some reason `clone.save(copy)` does not pass the 'copy' variable to the .save method. I even added some print statements to print all `args` and `kwarg` arguments, but both return empty lists/ dicts.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set a flag field in the model? Cleaner than `*kwargs` and `**args`.  Something like:

```
class AssessmentSubmission(models.Model):
    '''
    Your other fields here
    '''
    flag_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self):

    #check if a submission is older than the 'create a new one' threshold
    #Create a new one if that is the case

    delta = self.last_edited - self.start_date

    print(args)
    print(kwargs)

    if not self.flag_field:
        print('cloning!')

        if delta.days >= 14:

            clone = self
            clone.pk = None
            clone.flag_field = 1
            clone.save('copy')

    super(AssessmentSubmission, self).save()
```